# Many-to-one mapping (with non-primary-key column and "many" side as parent)

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring app there's the `Store` entity and `StoreImage` entity. `StoreImage` may be associated with several `Store`s (store company has one logo, but the company has multiple stores located in different places).

I've managed, I think, to get it working. Below I copy these 2 models and the mapping. I however am not sure if it's the proper practice. I'd be really grateful for some feedback and explanations of drawbacks of this implementation.

I've mostly based my code on [How to map a @ManyToOne association using a non-Primary Key column with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-a-manytoone-association-using-a-non-primary-key-column/) article.

```
@Table(name = "store")
@Entity(name = "Store")
public class Store {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String city;

    private String street;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "name",
            referencedColumnName = "store_name",
            insertable = false,
            updatable = false
    )
    private StoreImage image;

    // getters and setters
}
```

```
@Entity(name = "StoreImage")
@Table(name = "store_image")
public class StoreImage extends ImageModel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "store_name")
    @NaturalId
    private String storeName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "image")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Store> stores = new HashSet<>();

    public StoreImage(String imageUrl, String remoteId) {
        super(imageUrl, remoteId);
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```